# perl - how to remove specific word from string?

Tags: perl

I have a string "/project/pkt/sw/tool/xxx" and should be removed "sw/tool/xxx" from the original string.
Please let suggest me how to do it?

Input:

```
"/project/pkt/sw/tool/xxx";
```

Desired Output

```
"/project/pkt/"
```

Code

```
my $ str = "project/pkt/sw/tool/xxx";
$str =~ s|\w*/\w*/\w*$||;
print $str;
```

I am getting same original string here, please let me know how to remove last three words from the original string.

Comment: You've given an example of what you want to do, but we need to know what you want to do in the general case. Do you want to remove everything after the fourth / in the string? Do you want to remove the last three 'words' in the string? What would you want to happen if the input were "/one/two/three/four/five/six"? Or "one/two/three/"?

Comment: Last three words should be removed in my original string.

Comment: Do you want a mechanism for removing the last three words, no matter how long the string is?  Or is the point to preserve the first two words, no matter what they are?  Or is is "remove anything after, and including, sw/tool/"?  Unless we know what you actually mean you are likely to get useless answers.

Comment: Always , i need to be removed last three words from the original string. I dont need to preserve any prefix strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex modifies `$str` to remove the last three words as defined in the question.

```
$str =~ s|\w*/\w*/\w*$||;
```

Comment: with above regular expression , i am getting same original string.

Comment: I tested it and it works. I had quotes in the answer to begin with, and I edited them out. Did you try before I edited it?

Comment: also: `s|(/\w+){3}$||`

Comment: kobame - that removes the 3rd `/` as well. A pity as it is clearer